# Why am I getting an sqlite3 error 14 (unable to open database) when calling step on an sqlite3_stmt?

Tags: sqlite

I am experiencing an *SQLite* error when attempting to step on an `sqlite3_stmt`. Surprisingly, I got the error 14: *unable to open database file*.

This is confusing as I opened the database earlier, and successfully submitted an insert into one of the tables. At no point did I close the database.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT to table A
INSERT to table B
END TRANSACTION
```

When I attempt to run the second insert command, I get the failure.

Does anyone have any idea of what might cause this issue?

Comment: Try to install a logging function with [sqlite3_config](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/config.html) and SQLITE_CONFIG_LOG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely SQLite is unable create/write to a required temporary file for the transaction. Check your temp location.

See [sqlite3_temp_directory](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/temp_directory.html).

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me.  chowning the dir to the user opening the db https://www.pantz.org/software/sqlite/unabletoopendbsqliteerror.html