# I'm receiving "SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sqlite

I am writing an ASP.NET web API on .NET Framework 4.7.2. I would like to have a SQLite database in a file on my harddrive. Then I could access the database using a SqliteConnection.

In my code, I call `var db = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=testDB.sqlite");` to create the SqliteConnection. Then I call `db.Open();`. This function throws a Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException containing the error "SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'."

I tried to create the testDB.sqlite file manually, but I wasn't sure where to put it. I am not asking the SqliteConnection to create any directories. I am not writing a UWP app (because ASP.NET is different from UWP, correct?). I've tried both a relative path and an absolute path. I even deleted the entire project and used the Visual Studio project creation wizard to regenerate it. I do not know what else to try.

I've created a minimal reproducible example [here](https://github.com/AugustZellmer/SQLiteDoesNotWork). You should be able to just pop this right into Visual Studio. Besides the plumbing, the example is literally only 2 lines long. Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to look at this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343380/why-am-i-getting-an-sqlite3-error-14-unable-to-open-database-when-calling-step

Comment: Please make sure to [edit] question to provide necessary example *inline in the question as text*, links to some other sites are not considered [MCVE] from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask point of view. Also don't include text unrleated to the problem - "includes MCVE" is pointless part of the title as one is naturally expected to find one in the question. In this case it also looks like trolling when there is no actual code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

For your project try to install dependece: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
and correct connection string in your code like this:

```
var db = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=file:testDB.sqllite;Mode=ReadWrite;");
db.Open();
```

Microsoft.Data.Sqlite is using filename in Data Sourse as URI:
https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html#urifilenamesinsqlite3open

I created sqllite database with SQLliteStudio: https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/releases

Added testDB.sqllite in project and set property "Copy to Output directory" :"Copy if newer".

After those steps "Open" worked success

Comment: I'll try this later and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'd accidentally mixed up the versions of the Nuget packages added to projects within my solution.

I had a reference to the following inside the `.csproj`:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.10" />`
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.1"`
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.1" />`

Updateding packages to:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.10" />`
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.10"`
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.10" />`

Resolved this error for us inside a UWP project.